# arduino weather shield and wind speed

Tags: hardware, software

I have Arduino Mega and Weather Shield. I want to calculate wind speed.

```
float get_wind_speed()
{

float deltaTime = millis() - lastWindCheck; //750ms 

deltaTime /= 1000.0; 

  float windSpeed = (float)windClicks / deltaTime; //3 / 0.750s = 4

  windClicks = 0; //Sıfırla ve yeni oluşan rüzgarı izle
  lastWindCheck = millis();

  windSpeed *= 1.492; //4 * 1.492 = 5.968MPH

 Serial.println();
 Serial.print("Windspeed :");
 Serial.println(windSpeed);

 return(windSpeed);
}
```

But when I run my code I see two windspeed value. First one is windspeed=0.0 or any value. Second one is windspeed=nan.

How can I make it better?

Answer (score 1):

When debugging a problem like this one, print out values of the variables that the calculation depends on.

In this case, you may find that both `windClicks` and `deltaTime` are 0 or 0.0.  The IEEE 754 floating-point-operations specification dictates a result of `NaN` (not-a-number) for various zero over zero calculations.  It dictates a result of `+Inf` or `-Inf` for calculations like 7/0.0 or -13/0.0.  [See, for example, the stackoverflow question, [Why does division by zero with floating point (or double precision) numbers not throw an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12954193).]

If arithmetic generates a `NaN` or `+Inf` result, subsequent arithmetic using that result will also produce `NaN` or `+Inf` results.

To deal with the problem, you could use `deltaTime > 0` as a required pre-condition for calculation of `windSpeed`.  That is, have an if-statement protecting the calculation block.